# how to get the records till now by using linq in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have bunch of records coming form the API response, but I just need to add some of the records in my database. I'm getting last record inserted in the database that is - fromDate = {7/5/2018 9:13:54 AM}. i need to get the records between that fromdate to latest record. But when tried, I'm getting 0 records due to datetime condition wrong.

sample data

```
RecordDateTime = {5/3/2018 7:29:00 PM}
fromDate= {7/5/2018 12:00:00 AM}
```

### Code:

```
List<TransformerDetails> Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TransformerDetails>>(responseString);
//Count = 10043
if (fromDate.HasValue)
{
    Pirs = Pirs.Where(x => x.RecordDateTime > fromDate).ToList(); 
    //fromDate= {7/5/2018 12:00:00 AM}
    //count=0
}
```

### Model

```
public DateTime RecordDateTime
{
    get
    {
        string updtime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
        return Convert.ToDateTime(updtime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course you are getting no records. DateTime.Now is May 10th, 2018, how do you expect to get records greater than a future date of July 5th, 2018?

Comment: @krishna Please format your code properly. I did it once for you, I'm not going to do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get the records between now and July 5th 2018, this is how you do it :

```
Pirs = Pirs.Where(x => x.RecordDateTime < fromDate && x.RecordDateTime > DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

Other than that, honestly... Your question seems to be concerning dates that haven't yet occurred, which is suspicious and I wonder if you really took enough time to think about what you are doing.